# ResourceNotFound: Resource could not be discovered - Microsoft Graph

Tags: php, api, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I'm developing a service to synchronize Dolibarr calendar with Outlook calendar.

I'm first trying to create an event in the Outlook mailbox.
I have looked on different forums and tried many different things, but I still have this issue:

**Code: ResourceNotFound**

**Message: Resource could not be discovered.**

I have created an API on Microsoft Azure with the following API authorizations:

[image]

**Step 1: Authentication & authorization**

I'm asking the user authorization to create an event in the calendar:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/########/oauth2/V2.0/authorize?
client_id=2c4*******
&scope=openid+offline_access+User.Read+Calendars.Read+Calendars.ReadWrite
&response_type=code
```

**Step 2: Get access token**

Then I get a `code` to request the `access-token`:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/########/oauth2/V2.0/token
```

with the following data (json):

```
"grant_type" => "authorization_code",
"code" => "{previous_code}",
"client_id" => "2c4*******",
"client_secret" => "p0i********"
```

I finally get the token and seem to be well authenticated.

**Step 3: POST an event**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events`

with the following headers:

```
'Content-Type: application.json'
'Authorization: Bearer {token}'
```

and the following data (json):

```
"subject": "....",
"body": {
  "contentType": "HTML",
  "content": "..."
},
"start": {
  "dateTime": "2020-09-16 10:00:00",
  "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
},
"end": {
  "dateTime": "2020-09-16 13:00:00",
  "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

And I have this error

[image]

Do you have any idea why I have this issue?

(I precise I'm using my student account)

Comment: Please check if there is a mailbox present for the account which you are logging in with.

Comment: Are you still looking for help?

Comment: Share related info asked earlier by Shiva. Also try to get the detailed response log with the error (which will contain requestid, timestamp) of the error to analyze it.